# Is there a way to tell menu items to force non-SSL URLs?

Tags: menus, ssl

I've got a client site which uses SSL for only a small chunk of pages where users purchase subscriptions. So, for those pages, we just make sure that any links into them have hrefs with https://etc and everything's fine.

The problem is that once they're finished with the purchase and *exit* those pages using any links managed by the site theme menus, the SSL connection is retained. These URL references are not under our direct control, as they're just created by dragging the requisite page/category block around in the menu manager, so we can't adjust the http(s) portion.
This results in spurious security warnings about unsecured content on pages that shouldn't be secured anyway, and some issues with certain bits of scripting, etc.

How can we fix this? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WP HTTPS plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) will be your friend.

Comment: No don't use the plugin mentioned above use force // instead

Comment: That plugin (or "Really SSL") is the best solution. You already have an SSL certificate installed on the site, so you should use SSL on all pages. Besides, having SSL on all pages will increase your SEO/search rankings, and visitors won't see the security warnings (which might incline the visitor to leave your site).